# NHibernate QueryOver.List causing N+1

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Having a seemingly bizzare N+1 select problem in NHibernate. I am executing a query where I'm asking for a bunch of entities where one of its linked properties is null. I don't actually need the linked property to be returned in this case by NHibernate as its only for the purpose of selecting the right data.

First Entity is a booking Window

```
public class BookingWindow : Entity<BookingWindow>
{
    // Blah blah blah

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the booking order item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The booking order item.
    /// </value>
    public virtual BookingWindowOrderItem BookingOrderItem { get; set; }
}
```

And the BookingWindowOrderItem as follows

```
public class BookingWindowOrderItem : OrderItem
{
    // Blah blah blah

    public virtual BookingWindow BookingWindow { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the respective mappings

```
   public BookingWindowMap()
    {
        this.Schema("Customer");
        this.Table("BookingWindows");
        this.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        this.Component(x => x.WindowPeriod, m =>
        {
            m.Map(x => x.Min, "StartTime");
            m.Map(x => x.Max, "EndTime");
        });

        this.References(window => window.BookingOrderItem).PropertyRef("BookingWindow").Column("Id").LazyLoad().Nullable().ReadOnly();
        this.Map(x => x.Price);
        this.References(x => x.CustomerRoom).ForeignKey("RoomId").Column("RoomId");
    }
```

And

```
    public BookingWindowOrderItemMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue(1);
        this.References(x => x.BookingWindow).LazyLoad().Column("OrderItemForeignId").ForeignKey("OrderItemForeignId");
    }
```

Now When I execute the following query I get back the correct Booking windows that don't have an order item.

```
Session.QueryOver<BookingWindow>().Where(w => w.CustomerRoom.Id == Guid.Parse(roomId)).Left.JoinQueryOver(bw => bw.BookingOrderItem).WhereRestrictionOn(item => item.Id).IsNull.List<BookingWindow>();
```

So the first query gets issued to the database like so (the order item columns are selected which is a bit annoying but the real problem comes in a minute)

SELECT this_.Id as Id2_1_, this_.Price as Price2_1_, this_.RoomId as RoomId2_1_, this_.StartTime as StartTime2_1_, this_.EndTime as EndTime2_1_, bookingwin1_.Id as Id4_0_, bookingwin1_.Price as Price4_0_, bookingwin1_.Description as Descript4_4_0_, bookingwin1_.OrderId as OrderId4_0_, bookingwin1_.OrderItemParentId as OrderIte6_4_0_, bookingwin1_.OrderItemForeignId as OrderIte7_4_0_ FROM Customer.BookingWindows this_ left outer join Payment.OrderItem bookingwin1_ on this_.Id=bookingwin1_.OrderItemForeignId and bookingwin1_.OrderItemTypeId='1' WHERE this_.RoomId = ? and bookingwin1_.Id is null

But then for each booking window returned there is an extra select for the linked order item even though I haven't asked for it or need it. This happens within the query over method so I'm not doing any kind of iterating over the returned booking windows manually.

SELECT bookingwin0_.Id as Id4_0_, bookingwin0_.Price as Price4_0_, bookingwin0_.Description as Descript4_4_0_, bookingwin0_.OrderId as OrderId4_0_, bookingwin0_.OrderItemParentId as OrderIte6_4_0_, bookingwin0_.OrderItemForeignId as OrderIte7_4_0_ FROM Payment.OrderItem bookingwin0_ WHERE bookingwin0_.OrderItemForeignId=? and bookingwin0_.OrderItemTypeId='1'

Can anyone explain to me the error I have made here. Maybe its obvious but I've struggled for a few hours and at the end of my patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one weird part in your mapping: Using `References` as a one-to-one mapping style. Maybe it is intended, but this is causing that issue you have.

Firstly, as documentation says [References / many-to-one][1]

> References is for creating many-to-one relationships between two
>   entities, and is applied on the "many side." You're referencing a
>   single other entity, so you use the References method. #HasMany /
>   one-to-many is the "other side" of the References relationship, and
>   gets applied on the "one side."

*Other words, in the table of the `BookingWindowOrderItemMap` you store reference to `BookingWindow`. It could mean (by the DB Design), that there could be more records of OrderItem, referencing the same BookingWindow. But maybe this is what you want, and you check "uniqueness" elsewhere. The more I tried to understand your problem, I would vote for moving the reference to OrderItem in a column in the BookingWindow*

Problem revealed:

To your issue. When NHibernate recieves the list of `BookingWindow`, the next step is to build a proxy. In this process, all valueType/string properties are set, and for references... And for references NHibernate tries to prepare the lazy load.

Simplified version is, that into each property `BookingWindowOrderItem BookingOrderItem` is injected a *promise* for an instance of the `BookingWindowOrderItem`, to be returned when firstly touched. In standard cases, when mapping `References` is used, NHibernate in this moment already loaded from the table of the BookingWindow the `ReferenceId`.

In your case, this ReferenceID is represented by virtual, readonly 'current item ID'. The ID which definetly **exists**... but the reference **does not**! We've selected only `BookingWindow`s which has NULL instead of the reference.

But we do have **NOT NULL** Reference ID (representd by Current instance ID).

And we've used `.Left.JoinQueryOver`. So NHibernate is sure, that it already loaded all data in the first query... but is confused, because in his session is no OrderItem with the id equal to BookingWindow.ID/ReferenceId

That's the reason (why it tries to fix it... and does load it again)

So this is the answer, why NHibernate does "weird selects". Not a suggestion how to fix it ;) it could be another question and answer...

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this one. I can sort of now understand how this is being caused from you explanation and decided to make adjustments to stop this from happening.

Comment: Great to here that. Wish the best with NHibernate... a bit challenging to learn, but great once you know how to rule it.